# How can I use a table value in a WHERE clause in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query:

```
select *
from table 
inner join tableTwo 
on tableTwo.column = table.column
where columnTwo='THIS IS FIRST VALUE OF THIS COLUMN'
order by date DESC
```

On the Where clause, I want to use the result of this query:

```
select *
from table 
inner join tableTwo 
on tableTwo.column = table.column
```

This query produces a table with a column name of columnTwo. I want to use the data under column two in the WHERE clause like 
WHERE columnTwo={{ColumnData}}. How can I specifically achieve this? Sorry if my wording is bad, I am new to SQL.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: What does "first" mean? minimum? maximum? the value with the lowest id? Please update your question with that information

Comment: Table rows are not ordered. What do you mean by "first"? According to what order?

Comment: "Scalar subquery". There's even a tag. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html

SELECT *
FROM table 
INNER JOIN tableTwo 
on tableTwo.column = table.column
LIMIT 1

Comment: Table rows are not ordered. We don't know what the asker means by "first". So the question merits a comment about that, not an anwer. LIMIT can only be reasonably said to return the "first" when used with ORDER BY. PS Please explain why this is answer in your answer. Links should be for supplemental info. See [answer]. Also that link is about optimizing LIMIT & not the meaning of a query with LIMIT.